# Output of mysql database is html and js code

Tags: android

Hi I'm setting up a new test server by mysql and want to create a test app in android that get the username and password from client and if they correctly inputted, app show toast( yeaah + username )
but it show js and html code :(((

and at last of this toast is:

```
   <noscript> this site requires javascript to work , please enable javascript in your browser or use a browser with javascript support </noscript>
```

**This is the main activity :**

```
    package com.example.server;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static String Res="";
public static String res="";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new GetData("http://aysam1388mohammad.gigfa.com/test1.php", "mohammadreza").execute();

    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Main_BTN_Click);
    final TextView txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Main_Txt);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            txt.setText(Res+"\n"+res);

        }
    });

}
}
```

**this is the GetData class :**

```
       package com.example.server;

       import java.io.BufferedReader;
       import java.io.InputStreamReader;
       import java.io.OutputStream;
       import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
       import java.net.URL;
       import java.net.URLConnection;
       import java.net.URLEncoder;  

       import android.os.AsyncTask;

  public class GetData extends AsyncTask{
private String LInk;
private String USer;
public GetData (String Link,String User) {
    LInk = Link;
    USer=User;
}



protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
    try{
        String data=URLEncoder.encode("Username1","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(USer,"UTF8");

        URL Link=new URL(LInk);
        URLConnection Link_Connect=Link.openConnection();

        Link_Connect.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter WR=new OutputStreamWriter(Link_Connect.getOutputStream());
        WR.write(data);
        WR.flush();

        BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Link_Connect.getInputStream())); 
        StringBuilder Sb=new StringBuilder();

        String Line=null;

        while((Line=Reader.readLine())!=null) {
            Sb.append(Line);
        }

        MainActivity.res=Sb.toString(); //  "res"
        MainActivity.Res="Yeeeeeeah"; //    "res"

    }catch(Exception e) {
        MainActivity.Res="nooooo"; //   "res"
    }


    return "";
}


       }
```

I'm sorry because of my terrible English and thank you that read this stack.

oh I forget to say that I used a php file in mysql database to connect with my app.

**this is php file:**

```
   <?php 
$conect=mysql_connect("sql210.gigfa.com","gigfa_23465941","13882345");
mysql_select_db("gigfa_23465941_Db1",$conect);


$User=$_POST['username'];


$SqlQ="select * from User where Username='$User' ";
$result=mysql_Query($SqlQ);
$Row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($Row[0]){
print("yeah \n");

}else {print("noo");
}
print $Row[1];

mysql_close($conect);

?>
```

Comment: Try to change the Content-Type from your php code.

Comment: i did not understand what you mean sir.
would you please explain what must i do??
@FarukToptas

Comment: but im sure the php code is correct because i tested an output in that's web and it was ok @FarukToptas

Comment: It works with web. Because browser has no problem with text/html content type. It should be something like below from php side: 

$data = "{\"result\":\"yeah\"}"
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);